# How to merge Flask login with a Dash application?

Tags: python, flask, web-applications, plotly-dash

I have to design a web-app that provides Flask services and Dash services. For example I would like to create a login in Flask, combined with a Dash application. The problem is that I can't bind the flask login with dash. I would need a method like '@require_login' that filters access to even Dash services.
The code is as follows:

```
app_flask = Flask(__name__)

app_flask.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////login.db'
app_flask.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'thisissecret'

db = SQLAlchemy(app_flask)
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app_flask)

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(30), unique=True)

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))

@app_flask.route('/')
def index():
    user = User.query.filter_by(username='admin').first()
    login_user(user)
    return 'You are now logged in!'

@app_flask.route('/logout')
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return 'You are now logged out!'

@app_flask.route('/home')
@login_required
def home():
    return 'The current FLASK user is ' + current_user.username

# TODO how to add login_required for dash? 
app_dash = Dash(server=app_flask, url_base_pathname='/dash/')
app_dash.layout = html.H1('MY DASH APP')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app_dash.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This line, `app_dash = Dash(server=app_flask, url_base_pathname='/dash/')`, creates new `view_functions` in `app_flask` identified by its `url_base_pathname`.

You can debug and inspect the value of `app_flask.view_functions` before and after the creation of `app_dash`.

Now that we know which `view_functions` are created by `app_dash`, we can apply `login_required` to them manually.

```
for view_func in app_flask.view_functions:
    if view_func.startswith(app_dash.url_base_pathname):
        app_flask.view_functions[view_func] = login_required(app_flask.view_functions[view_func])
```

The `app_dash` endpoints will now be protected.

Comment: SALUTE TO YOU! IT WORKS

Comment: Doesn't work anymore: https://community.plot.ly/t/how-protect-dash-routes-with-login-after-dash-1-0-release/25114

Comment: Replacing `app_dash.url_base_pathname` with `app_dash.config['url_base_pathname']` works. Thanks for this solution. +1

Comment: Spent 2 days working on this problem and this solution worked for me.  Thanks!!!!

Comment: This solution worked 99% perfect. Thank you!

With Dash v2.1.0, I had to modify slightly:

Suggest to change

"app_dash.url_base_pathname"

to

"app_dash.config['routes_pathname_prefix']"

Answer (score 7):

It would be better if you block all requests by using `@app.before_request`, and only allow the request if logged in or if the endpoint is marked as public.

````
def check_route_access():
    if request.endpoint is None:
        return redirect("/login")
 
    func = app.view_functions[request.endpoint]
    if (getattr(func, "is_public", False)):
        return  # Access granted

    # check if user is logged in (using session variable)
    user = session.get("user", None)
    if not user:
        redirect("/login")
    else:
        return  # Access granted```
````

Now all endpoints will be checked, even dash app endpoints.

Add this decorator named `public_route`:

```
def public_route(function):
    function.is_public = True
    return function
```

And add the decorator to the public methods, like login, error pages etc.

```
@public_route
@app.route("/login")
def login():
   # show/handle login page
   # call did_login(username) when somebody successfully logged in


def did_login(username):
    session["user"] = username
```

This way you never need the `@login_required` anymore because all endpoints require login unless stated otherwise by `@public_route`.

Answer (score 1):

A solution : session from flask (work with cookie)

`from flask import session`

it's an exemple :

`@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    # I think here it's good
    session["uid"] = user_id
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))`

`# TODO how to add login_required for dash? 
if "uid" in session :
    app_dash = Dash(server=app_flask, url_base_pathname='/dash/')
    app_dash.layout = html.H1('MY DASH APP')`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In this way, however, the sessions are used out of context.
"RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.

This typically means that you attempted to use that functionality
an active HTTP request. Consult the documentation on testing for
information about how to avoid this problem. "

A possible solution could be to save the session in a database. Do you think it's the best thing to do? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It's a solution but i think it's too much, if it's a small application maybe don'y use Flask-Login but session only ? if you want to use Flask-Login like this maybe find an another way to implement it ?

Comment: I am having the same issue. I have data captured in the flask application and I want to pass it to the dash route. The session object generates the same error as above. I have a sqlite db that I am accessing I will insert the data and then query the data back in the dash app. I can't come up with a better way?