# How to hold Plotly dash app behind protected route

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash, flask-jwt-extended

I have a plotly dash app which I would like to hold behind a route that is protected with a JWT. My end goal is to contain this in an iframe on a separate route, but I only want the user to be able to get the html of th dash app if they have an access token.

I have retried returning the app itself in a get request.

App.py

```py
import dash
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_jwt_extended import (
    JWTManager, jwt_required, create_access_token,
    get_jwt_identity
)

server = Flask(__name__)

server.config['JWT_SECRET_KEY'] = 'super-secret'  # Change this!
jwt = JWTManager(server)

@server.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    if not request.is_json:
        return jsonify({"msg": "Missing JSON in request"}), 400

    username = request.json.get('username', None)
    password = request.json.get('password', None)
    if not username:
        return jsonify({"msg": "Missing username parameter"}), 400
    if not password:
        return jsonify({"msg": "Missing password parameter"}), 400

    if username != 'test' or password != 'test':
        return jsonify({"msg": "Bad username or password"}), 401

    # Identity can be any data that is json serializable
    access_token = create_access_token(identity=username)
    return jsonify(access_token=access_token), 200

@server.route('/')
@jwt_required
def index():
    return 'Hello world flask app'

app = dash.Dash(
   __name__,
   server=server,
   routes_pathname_prefix='/'
)

app.config.suppress_callback_exceptions = True
```

Index.py

```py
from app import app
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from combination_1 import Combination
import callbacks

app.layout = html.Div([
   dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=False),
   html.Div(id="root_div")

])

@app.callback(
   Output('root_div', 'children'),
   [Input('url', 'pathname')]
)
def attatch_graphs(pathname):
   return Combination(comb_id='comb_1').return_div()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run_server()
```

Answer (score 3):

I'll share a few resources I found researching the question:

1. Dash provides a [library named `dash-auth`](https://pypi.org/project/dash-auth/), which you can install using `pip install dash-auth`
2. Once you install the library, you'll be able to use `import dash_auth`, and you'll notice sub-modules for [HTTP Basic Auth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication), [OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth), and "*PlotlyAuth*".  "PlotlyAuth" has been deprecated, according to the text in `from dash_auth.plotly_auth import deprecation_notice`
3. The source code for this module appears to be https://github.com/plotly/dash-auth
4. Documentation is available at https://dash.plotly.com/authentication and a promotional page is available at https://plotly.com/dash/authentication/
5. Presumably, JWT can be integrated using Flask's `Response.set_cookie`.  [Here are details about that approach](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/building-a-dashboard-app-using-plotlys-dash-a-complete-guide-from-beginner-to-pro-e7657a4eb707), notice the author uses `rep.set_cookie('custom-auth-session', username)`
6. There's an example on Github which uses [Dash, Flask, and Flask-Login](https://github.com/RafaelMiquelino/dash-flask-login/blob/master/server.py).  This configuration also exists in a [separate StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52286507/how-to-merge-flask-login-with-a-dash-application).  However, this library [doesn't supports JWT](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/issues/253).  You may be able to achieve a similar architecture using the Flask-JWT-Extended library.