# Integrating Okta OIDC with Dash Application

Tags: python, flask, openid-connect, plotly-dash

I'm trying to integrate Okta OIDC authentication and Dash into a Flask app, so that a user would only be able to view the Dash app once they signed in using our org's Okta SSO

Trying:

```
from flask import Blueprint, Flask, jsonify, redirect, render_template_string, url_for
from flask_oidc import OpenIDConnect
from okta import UsersClient
import dash

oidc = OpenIDConnect()
okta_client = UsersClient("https://dev-XXXXXX.okta.com",
            "somesecret")

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config.from_mapping(
SECRET_KEY="testkey",
OIDC_CLIENT_SECRETS="/app/appname/client_secrets.json",
OIDC_COOKIE_SECURE= False,
OIDC_CALLBACK_ROUTE="/oidc/callback",
OIDC_SCOPES=["openid", "email", "profile"],
OIDC_ID_TOKEN_COOKIE_NAME="oidc_token",
DEBUG_TB_INTERCEPT_REDIRECTS = False)

oidc.init_app(app)

dash_app.layout = layout.layout
callbacks.register_dash_callbacks(dash_app)
dash_app.run_server(debug=True)

@app.route("/" , methods=["GET"])
@oidc.require_login
def redirect_to_app():
    return redirect(url_for(dash_app.config.requests_pathname_prefix))
```

gives me the following:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte
```

The app works just fine and integrates well into the Flask app. I've tried researching but wasn't able to find anything useful.

I could also get it to work by separating it out into a blueprint like so:

```
home_blueprint = Blueprint("home", __name__, url_prefix="/")
@home_blueprint.route("/" , methods=["GET"])
@oidc.require_login
def index():
    return redirect(url_for('/dash/'))
```

But then accessing the app directly via `localhost:5000/dash/` was still possible without authorization.

Thank you in advance for your help.

EDIT:
Here the complete traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/pyenv/versions/3.8.0/envs/customer-feedback-hub/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/pyenv/versions/3.8.0/envs/customer-feedback-hub/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ddtrace/vendor/wrapt/wrappers.py", line 602, in __call__
    return self._self_wrapper(self.__wrapped__, self._self_instance,
  File "/pyenv/versions/3.8.0/envs/customer-feedback-hub/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ddtrace/contrib/flask/helpers.py", line 20, in wrapper
    return func(pin, wrapped, instance, args, kwargs)
  File "/pyenv/versions/3.8.0/envs/customer-feedback-hub/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ddtrace/contrib/flask/patch.py", line 331, in traced_wsgi_app
    return wrapped(environ, start_response)
  File "/pyenv/versions/3.8.0/envs/customer-feedback-hub/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/pyenv/versions/3.8.0/envs/customer-feedback-hub/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ddtrace/vendor/wrapt/wrappers.py", line 602, in __call__
    return self._self_wrapper(self.__wrapped__, self._self_instance,
  File "/pyenv/versions/3.8.0/envs/customer-feedback-hub/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ddtrace/contrib/flask/helpers.py", line 20, in wrapper
    return func(pin, wrapped, instance, args, kwargs)
  File "/pyenv/versions/3.8.0/envs/customer-feedback-hub/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ddtrace/contrib/flask/helpers.py", line 29, in wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/pyenv/versions/3.8.0/envs/customer-feedback-hub/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/pyenv/versions/3.8.0/envs/customer-feedback-hub/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/pyenv/versions/3.8.0/envs/customer-feedback-hub/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/pyenv/versions/3.8.0/envs/customer-feedback-hub/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1816, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "/pyenv/versions/3.8.0/envs/customer-feedback-hub/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1833, in finalize_request
    response = self.process_response(response)
  File "/pyenv/versions/3.8.0/envs/customer-feedback-hub/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ddtrace/vendor/wrapt/wrappers.py", line 602, in __call__
    return self._self_wrapper(self.__wrapped__, self._self_instance,
  File "/pyenv/versions/3.8.0/envs/customer-feedback-hub/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ddtrace/contrib/flask/helpers.py", line 20, in wrapper
    return func(pin, wrapped, instance, args, kwargs)
  File "/pyenv/versions/3.8.0/envs/customer-feedback-hub/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ddtrace/contrib/flask/helpers.py", line 29, in wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/pyenv/versions/3.8.0/envs/customer-feedback-hub/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2112, in process_response
    response = handler(response)
  File "/pyenv/versions/3.8.0/envs/customer-feedback-hub/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ddtrace/vendor/wrapt/wrappers.py", line 554, in __call__
    return self._self_wrapper(self.__wrapped__, instance,
  File "/pyenv/versions/3.8.0/envs/customer-feedback-hub/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ddtrace/contrib/flask/wrappers.py", line 23, in trace_func
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/pyenv/versions/3.8.0/envs/customer-feedback-hub/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_debugtoolbar/__init__.py", line 202, in process_response
    response_html = response.data.decode(response.charset)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54115197/13122427) post, whih ended up solving my problem simply by replacing `login_required` with `oidc.require_login`. Turns out the invalid start byte was related to another bug I had.

```
app = Flask(__name__)


    app.config.from_mapping(
    SECRET_KEY="testkey",
    OIDC_CLIENT_SECRETS="XXX",
    OIDC_COOKIE_SECURE= False,
    OIDC_CALLBACK_ROUTE="/oidc/callback",
    OIDC_SCOPES=["openid", "email", "profile"],
    OIDC_ID_TOKEN_COOKIE_NAME="oidc_token",
    DEBUG_TB_INTERCEPT_REDIRECTS = False
    )



    oidc.init_app(app)

    dash_app = dash.Dash(__name__,
                    server = app,
                    url_base_pathname='/dash/'
                    )


    for view_func in app.view_functions:
        if view_func.startswith(dash_app.config['url_base_pathname']):
            app.view_functions[view_func] = oidc.require_login(app.view_functions[view_func])


    dash_app.layout = html.Div([intro_div, navbar, exec_dashboard, body])
    register_dash_callbacks(dash_app)
```